# Creating a factory inside the state and getting the id of itself in Laravel

Tags: laravel, factory

I am developing a Laravel application. I am using factories in my application especially for unit testing and setting them up, but I am having an issue with setting up the factory with state. Here is my database structure:

### Bid

```
id, amount, created_at, updated_at, user_id
```

Then I have another model as follows:

### BidLog

```
id, bid_status, created_at, updated_at, bid_id
```

The database structure is pretty straight forward. The thing is the BidLog will only be created in the event listener of the Bid. It only exists when the Bid exists. It is basically the state of the Bid. So when I set up the factory for the BidLog, I set up something like this.

BidLogFactory.php

```
$factory->define(BidLog::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $bid = Bid::inRandomOrder()->first();
    return [
        'bid_id' => $bid->id,
        'bid_status' => 'open'//Bid factory will override this value
    ];
});
```

Then I set up the states of the BidFactory like this.

```
$factory->state(Bid::class, 'open', function ($faker) {
    $bidLog = factory(BidLog::class)->create([
       'bid_status' => 'open',
       'bid_id' => //how can I get the bid id here?
    ]);
    return [
       'updated_at' => now()
    ];
});
```

The thing is how can get the Bid id in the state callback function? Or how can I set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> passing using callback function (closure)

use like that

```
$factory->state(Bid::class, 'open', function ($faker) {
    $bidLog = factory(BidLog::class)->create([
       'bid_status' => 'open',
       'bid_id' => function(){
           return   Bid::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        }
    ]);
    return [
       'updated_at' => now()
    ];
});
```

use `afterCreatingState` method in here(i think) for more into [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#writing-factories)

```
$factory->state(Bid::class, 'open', [])
        ->afterCreatingState(Bid::class,'open',function($bid,$faker) { 
              factory(BidLog::class)->create([
                  'bid_status' => 'open',
                  'bid_id' => $bid->id
             ]);
         });
```

Comment: No man. It is not. It is gonna give me the random bid id. What I want is something like this $this->id;

Comment: @WaiYanHein i updated my answer i think it will be useful to u

Answer (score 0):

I was faced same problem So, I share example with sample code

suppose, I have **Income table** for save total amount of income & there are **income_records** another table for represent detailed data of Income table data

**Income Table**

```
id, date, amount, created_at, updated_at
```

**income_records**

```
id, income_id , etc... many more other data fields
```

Now, I wants to enter fake testing data using Laravel Factory, then you can do as like below for get income_id named foreign key from income table's primary key

here I have **`Income`** Model for income_table & **`IncomeRecord`** Model for income_records table

Now I write below code in run() function of DatabaseSeeder class file

```
 <?php 
  $incomes = Income::factory(10)
            ->create(); // fake plot's Income create for companies
 
  $incomes->each(function($income) {
        IncomeRecord::factory()
                 ->state([
                        'income_id' => $income->id,
                 ])->create();
  });
 ?>
```

I hope this one helps to you...

> Note:- I used **Laravel 8** version... it may be will not works for below versions. So, Please Test it for other versions & if its works then Please edit my answer about Laravel version details